# Gather Table Names + Data using mysqli and php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to get the column names and data from a table using mysqli and php. Any help is appreciated.

I know how to do this in java by more or less this code:

```
    String [] header= new String[numberOfColumns-1];

//Code to get column names in header array

String table = "<table><tr>"

for(int i=0;i<numberOfColumns-1;i++){
    table= table + "<td>" + header[i] + </td>;
}
table = table + </tr>;
while(result.next()!=null){
    table = table + <tr>
    for (int j = 0 ; j < numberOfColumns-1 ; j++){
        table = table + <td> + result.getString[j] + </td>
    }
    table = table + </tr>
}
```

But i have no idea how to do it in php. Each table is different but what i have to far for the one table:

```
include("config.php");
    session_start();

    $sql = ($_POST['q']);
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>First Name</td>";
    echo "<td>Last Name</td>";
    echo "<td>Date of Birth</td>";
    echo "<td>Contact Details</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['fname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['lname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['dob'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowitem['contact'] . "</td>";*/
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; //end table tag
```

EDIT: Is the implementation of the fetch_fields correct?

```
include("config.php");
    session_start();

    $sql = ($_POST['q']);
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    $finfo = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($finfo as $val) {
        echo "<td>" . $val->name . "</td>"
    } 
    echo "</tr>";
    while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($x =0; $x < count($finfo);$x++){
            echo "<td>" . $rowitem[$x] . "/td";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

EDIT 2: Database Connection.php

```
<<?php

    include("config.php");
    session_start();

    $sql = ($_GET['q']);

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    echo "<table border='1' class='table_info'>";
    $finfo = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($finfo as $val) {
        echo "<td>" . $val->name . "</td>";
    } 
    echo "</tr>";
    while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $value) { (line 18)
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; //end table tag

   ?>
```

Error:
Notice: Undefined variable: row in databaseConnection.php on line 18

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in databaseConnection.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

You can call `mysqli_fetch_fields` on the `$result` object, and retrieve the `name` property for each object in the returned array. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) for examples.

Comment: is the implementation of your advice correct? Bit new to PHP

Comment: looks good. did it work? add a semicolon inside the foreach loop.

Comment: this is part of a larger script to send a sql from javascript to php , draw the table and send it back to html. Id let know how it goes but it looks promising

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. Use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to grab the names of the keys from an associative array:

   ```
    $rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $header = array_keys($rowitem);
   ```
2. Use [`mysqli_fetch_fields()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) to grab the field objects, and parse out the names into an array using [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

   ```
    // Helper function to use in array_map
    // (For PHP < 5.3. If >= 5.3.0, use the second version)
    function getFieldName($field) { return $field->name; }

    // For PHP < 5.3:
    $header = array_map("getFieldName", mysqli_fetch_fields($result));

    // For PHP >= 5.3.0:
    $header = array_map(function($o) { return $o->name; }, mysqli_fetch_fields($result));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can use $result->fetch_fields() to get the field information from the result and this includes the name of each field.

For what you're trying to acheive this code should work for pretty much any table/query:

```
<?php

/* Connect to mysql */    
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

/* Check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Your query */
$query = "SELECT * from table";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* Output HTML table */
    echo "<table border='1'>";

    /* Get field information for all returned columns */
    $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();

    /* Output each column name in first table row */
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($finfo as $val) {
        echo "<td>".$val->name."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    /* Fetch the result and output each row into a table row */
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    $result->free();

    echo "</table>";

}
$mysqli->close();
```

(Obviously you should never query a database from a $_POST variable without some serious sanitisation of the input, but I'll assume that was just for your convenience.)

Answer (score 0):

You can Echo in a table..

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql)
 if (!$result) {
   die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
$field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

// $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
// of $row to $cell variable
   foreach($row as $cell)
       echo "<td>$cell</td>";
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);`
```